# Ruby on Rail application generated with Happy Seed, need navbar explained

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml, bootstrap-sass

I am relatively new to building rails applications and I created am new rails application using [Happy Seed](http://seed.happyfuncorp.com/). I can't seem to figure out what exactly is happening in the header. Happy Seed generates an app using bootstrap-sass and haml. What I'm not sure about is, its the `= navbar do`, `= vertical do`, and `= horizontal do`. Is this something built into rails? Bootstrap? I have tried googling but couldn't find anything relevant. If anyone could point me towards any sort of documentation, that would be great.

Here is the "_header.html.haml" file:

```
= navbar position: :static do
  = vertical do
    = link_to root_path do
      %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-cloud
      Home
  = horizontal do
    = nav class: 'navbar-right' do
      = link_to 'Contact', ""
      = link_to 'About', ""
      = render partial: "application/account_dropdown"
```

And this is what it is generating when I view the source:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header"><button class="navbar-toggle" data-target="#navbar-collapse-7238422159" data-toggle="collapse" type="button"><span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span></button>
<li class="active"><a class="navbar-brand" href="/"><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-cloud'></span>
Home
</a></li>
</div>
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar-collapse-7238422159"><ul class="navbar-right nav navbar-nav"><li><a href="">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="">About</a></li>
<li class='dropdown'>
  <a aria-expanded='false' class='dropdown-toggle' data-toggle='dropdown' href='#' role='button'>
    Account <span class="caret"></span>
  </a>
  <ul class='dropdown-menu'>
    <!-- CONNECT -->
    <li><a href="/users/sign_in">Sign In</a></li>
    <li><a href="/users/sign_up">Sign Up</a></li>
  </ul>
</li>
</ul>
</div>

  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: It looks very much like bootstrap. The rails helpers generate generic markup like inputs, HTML elements etc. They do not generate any framework specific markup as rails is not opionated towards any CSS framework.

Comment: i think `= vertical`, `= horizontal`, etc are your happy_seed gem provided methods to generate bootstrap classes. not rails helper or bootstrap helper (bootstrap just gives you css files not helper methods)